# Ethernet is not working after upgrade ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04

Tags: networking, ethernet, 18.04

After upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04 the ethernet connection is not showing in networks.

I tried this.

```
 $   ifconfig 

enp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 28:f1:0e:33:c6:8c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 92859  bytes 31342466 (31.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 92859  bytes 31342466 (31.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.70  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::f604:8dc4:abd3:f1a9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e4:02:9b:10:39:f2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 419663  bytes 534953715 (534.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 324770  bytes 41353378 (41.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

That means laptop is detaching the ethernet cable but not showing in networks. Wifi is working fine. I already tried number of solutions but not working in my case. Please Help !

Comment: Try booting with your previous kernel that 17.10 was last using. Should be in your **Advanced Options** menu in grub boot loader.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029250/ubuntu-18-04-ethernet-disconnected-after-suspend?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa                                          here is the answer

Comment: The rtl8169 not loading after suspend is an old 16.04 bug.

Comment: it is also working in 18.04