# Scrolling not working after suspend, looking for permanent solution

Tags: 18.04, suspend, touchpad

I know this question has been asked before, but I want to see if anyone has a better solution than the one I have. I am using a Thinkpad 440p, previously with Ubuntu 18.04, currently with Ubuntu Mate 18.04. I've had this issue with elementary os and mint. When my computer suspends and I start it up again, the scrolling no longer works. The solution I found was to modprobe -r psmouse and modprobe psmouse. This fixes it instantly and I wrote a script to do it but I have to run the script everytime I resume from suspend. I was just wondering if anyone has a permanent solution.

Answer (score 5):

After some digging I used a combination of your solution and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029250/ubuntu-18-04-ethernet-disconnected-after-suspend) answer.

On Ubuntu 18.04, I placed the following script in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/psmouse-refresh`.  This reloads the module after suspend.

```
#!/bin/bash

# $1 is the state (pre or post)-sleep
if [[ $1 == post ]]; then
    modprobe -r psmouse
    modprobe psmouse
fi
```

make it executable

```
chmod +x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/psmouse-refresh
```

Answer (score 4):

The above worked for me using...

```
modprobe -r usbhid
modprobe usbhid
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, just with caution that just removing `usbhid` would disable all externally (usb) connected keyboards. That's why using && is important

Answer (score 2):

I tried a few workarounds. Following worked for me.

Updated the `/etc/default/grub` parameters as:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=0 quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop"
```

After this run:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

For testing the workaround:
Put your system to sleep using following command:

```
sudo systemctl suspend
```

Turn on the system and verify the mouse scroll wheel if it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! It solved both the scrolling issue and also the issue described in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1159957/thinkpad-trackpoint-and-trackpoint-keys-disabled-after-suspend/1159960#1159960