# Noticeable performance drop after suspend on 19.04

Tags: nvidia, suspend, performance, 19.04

I'm on precision 5530, i9, 32GB RAM, SSD, using nvidia drivers. When booting I have no performance issues. But if I suspend then resume I see performance and lag drop considerably.

I saw online this might be cpu throttling, but running `cpupower frequency-info` yields

```
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 4.80 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 4.80 GHz.
              The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
              within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 3.80 GHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
```

It doesn't seem to be throttled but everything is obviously slow.

I do see that the chrome gpu-process is using up 50-100% CPU, which is suggestive.

I didn't have this problem on 18.10.

What might cause this and how can I debug and fix?

Comment: Update: it seems that restarting Chrome fixes it, not sure if permanent. 

If it's just Chrome that can't handle a resume might report a bug there

Comment: Always a good idea right after resume to use `journalctl -xe` and review suspend / resume system messages.

Comment: `kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3

    kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3

     kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: WARN: xHC restore state timeout

    kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: PCI post-resume error -110!

 kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: HC died; cleaning up`

these lines seem relevant

Comment: I can post a script that may solve the issue but you won't be able to use USB mouse or USB keyboard to wakeup your system. It powers off all USB devices during suspend and powers them back on during resume (resume would be from from power button or laptop lid open). If the answer doesn't work let me know and I'll delete it right away.

Comment: Didn't try yet but I don't know how that would help, I don't have a USB mouse or keyboard

Comment: It may fix the `xhci_hcd` error message you get which is USB. The script doesn't fix USB mouse and/or keyboard. It prevents them from resuming with keypress or mouse movement. If you don't have USB mouse or keyboard then the loss of function won't effect you. Also you just have a plain old SSD not a NVMe M.2 Gen 3.0 x 4 SSD right?

Comment: PC401 NVMe SK hynix 1TB (80006E00)

Comment: Oh if it's NVMe you probably need the kernel parameter for it. I'll dig that up after work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo -H gedit /lib/systemd/system-sleep/custom-xhci_hcd`

Copy these lines into the editor:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Original script was using /bin/sh but shellcheck reporting warnings.

# NAME: custom-xhci_hcd
# PATH: /lib/systemd/system-sleep
# CALL: Called from SystemD automatically
# DESC: Suspend broken for USB3.0 as of Oct 25/2018 various kernels all at once

# DATE: Oct 28 2018.

# NOTE: From comment #61 at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/522998

TMPLIST=/tmp/xhci-dev-list

# Original script was: case "${1}" in hibernate|suspend)

case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    echo "$0: Going to $2..."
    echo -n '' > $TMPLIST
          for i in `ls /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/ | egrep '[0-9a-z]+\:[0-9a-z]+\:.*$'`; do
              # Unbind xhci_hcd for first device XXXX:XX:XX.X:
               echo -n "$i" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/unbind
           echo "$i" >> $TMPLIST
          done
        ;;
  post/*)
    echo "$0: Waking up from $2..."
    for i in `cat $TMPLIST`; do
              # Bind xhci_hcd for first device XXXX:XX:XX.X:
              echo -n "$i" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/bind
    done
    rm $TMPLIST
        ;;
esac
```

Save the file and exit the editor. Then use:

```bash
sudo chmod a+x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/custom-xhci_hcd
```

After rebooting your suspend / resume issues will hopefully be resolved. If not let me know and I'll delete this answer.

---

## NVMe M.2 "gum stick" SSD

These tiny SSD's pack a powerful punch but require special attention in regards to suspend/resume as per this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1655100). Edit the file `/etc/default/grub` and search for this line:

```bash
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash ... acpiphp.disable=1 pcie_aspm=force"
```

Don't add the ... but some place after the other parameters add `acpiphp.disable=1`. Do not add the `acpi_aspm=force` though unless adding the first option alone doesn't work.

Save the file and use `sudo update-grub`. Then reboot to test.

Comment: It's taking a long time to get to the login screen after resume, around 30 seconds, but the performance issues seem to have gone away. Does it make sense that this script would take so long? It could also be something else I tried

Comment: On my NVMe system it adds a second or two to power off and on all the USB devices. It might be related to the kernel parameter for NVMe I commented on ten minutes ago though.

Comment: Performance issues came back after a few suspend/resume cycles, so this isn't solving the core issue

Comment: @ike As promised earlier I've updated the answer.

Answer (score -2):

It could be related to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/671932.

What have done each time it's reproduced that I restarted the `thermald` service:

```bsh
sudo systemctl restart thermald.service
```

Comment: that's an ancient bug report that was marked invalid...