# On Ubuntu 18.04, ethernet through thunderbolt is detected on reboot but loses connection eventually

Tags: networking, ethernet, thunderbolt

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell XPS laptop. Half of my disk is Windows, the other half is Ubuntu.

When I reboot, I get the little triangular guy in my top right indicating that I have Ethernet but then after a while I find myself on WiFi and when I go to my *Settings > Devices > Thunderbolt* it says nothing detected and when I go to my network it doesn't seem to find anything related to my Ethernet.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Had the same problem.
The following answer solved it for me https://askubuntu.com/a/1030154/647310 Had to replace r8169 with my specific driver though.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.