# wireless network connection fails after suspending

Tags: wireless, network-manager, suspend

`sudo service network-manager restart` duplicates this problem, as well as trying to select another or the same network again.

Wi-Fi only works after rebooting. The wired connection works fine.
I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

The output of `sudo lshw -C network` when Wi-Fi is working is:

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 9c:30:5b:d2:fa:8b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723de ip=192.168.0.87 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:129 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1000000-b100ffff
```

And when Wi-Fi is not working:

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 9c:30:5b:d2:fa:8b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723de latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
       resources: irq:129 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1000000-b100ffff
```

I tried without success:

- `sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service`
- Reloading the `rtl8723de` driver by running:

  ```bsh
  sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sudo modprobe rtl8723de
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that `sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de` did not really unload the driver. This can be checked by `lsmod` or `lsmod | grep 8723de`. If the driver is loaded, it is listed in the output, if not, the driver is unloaded.

To unload, I had to use the command `rmmod` and for some reason to unload the driver I had to call it by `8723de`.

So I did:

```bsh
sudo rmmod 8723de
```

And then reloaded the driver:

```bsh
sudo modprobe rtl8723de
```

The Internet connection started working then.

I automated this adapting the accepted solution from this site:

- [Ubuntu 18.04 - Ethernet disconnected after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029250/ubuntu-18-04-ethernet-disconnected-after-suspend)

Type `sudo nano /lib/systemd/system-sleep/rtl8723de-refresh`. Insert:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

PROGNAME=$(basename "$0")
state=$1
action=$2

function log {
    logger -i -t "$PROGNAME" "$*"
}

log "Running $action $state"

if [[ $state == post ]]; then
    rmmod 8723de \
    && log "Removed rtl8723de" \
    && modprobe rtl8723de \
    && log "Inserted rtl8723de"
fi
```

Save and exit with <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd>.

Make executable with:

```bsh
chmod +x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/rtl8723de-refresh
```

As a remark, I got the driver from this site: https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de.git

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me in Debian 10, but I had to eliminate the double `[[` `]]` symbols in favor of `[` `]`. I leave it here in case someone has the same issue. I also had to add `"` in certain places.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

PROGNAME=$(basename "$0")
state=$1
action=$2

function log {
    logger -i -t "$PROGNAME" "$*"
}

log "Running $action $state"

if [ "${1}" == "post" ]; then
    rmmod 8723de \
    && log "Removed rtl8723de" \
    && modprobe rtl8723de \
    && log "Inserted rtl8723de"
fi
```