# Using Apple Thunderbolt 2 Ethernet adapter on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, server, ethernet, thunderbolt

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 Server on my 2014 Macbook Pro and it all works great with the USB to ethernet adapter. However, when I try to use the Thunderbolt 2 to ethernet adapter I can't get the network connection to work. Running `ip a` shows (what I think is) the Thunderbolt interface (ens9) as DOWN, so I ran `sudo ip link ens9 up`. Then the Macbook shows up as a device in my router, but I still can't access it (have a web server running on it that works fine with the USB adapter). Running `ping google.com` gives: `ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`.

I haven't installed any drivers, just simply plugged in the Thunderbolt adapter and booted up. Would be very happy for some help to troubleshoot. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:
Running `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` gives:

```yaml
# This is the network config written in 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enx00f76f6f62ca:
      dhcp4: true
    version: 2
```

And running `sudo lshw -C network` gives:

```
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:18 memory:b0600000-b0607fff memory:b0400000-b05fffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM57762 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       logical name: ens9
       version: 00
       serial: 18:7e:b9:0a:c7:d6
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 firmware=57762-a1.10 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:19 memory:bcc00000-bcc0ffff memory:bcc10000-bcc1ffff memory:b0c00000-b0c0ffff
```

Comment: You probably need to edit /etc/netplan/*.yaml to reflect the new device name. Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `sudo lshw -C network` with the Thunderbolt dongle plugged in. Do you have Access Control enabled in your router? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I've edited the post with the info you requested. Not sure if I have Access Control on the router, I think not. Thanks for helping out, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `sudo lshw -C network` is correctly showing that the **Thunderbolt 2 to ethernet** adapter as ens9, then your /etc/netplan/*.yaml should look like this...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens9:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

Comment: Thank you so much! That solves my issue. For anyone else looking into configuring netplan, here's a good list of examples: https://netplan.io/examples/