# netplan networkd no ipv4 from dhcp

Tags: dhcp, netplan, systemd-networkd

I've been trying to have ubuntu server running on my **MacBook Pro (15-inch, Late 2011)** for the whole day, both `20.04` and `21.10`, fighting with netplan and I cannot seem to be able to have `ens9` (Thunderbolt 2 network adapter - seems to work fine from this post: [Using Apple Thunderbolt 2 Ethernet adapter on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1317168/using-apple-thunderbolt-2-ethernet-adapter-on-ubuntu-20-04)) getting an `ipv4` from the DHCP.
I read tons of posts all over the place, it seems trivial but I still cannot get it to work :/

My `/etc/netplan` currently looks like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens9:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
```

But honestly, at this point, I've lost track of how many times I changed it. I pretty much tried everything I found searching for all the possible permutations of the words:
ubuntu, server, 20.04, 21.10, dhcp, ipv4, -static, -NetworkManager, not working, not getting IP, -ipv6, MacBook pro, ens9, netplan, systemd-networkd.

Whenever I `ip a` it `ens9` has only an `ipv6` (for some reason, I don't use `ipv6` in my network nor my DHCP assigns `ipv6` addresses, so I've no idea where it comes from tbh) no routing table and no nameserver assigned, which makes me suspect is not even trying to "dhcp anything".
Even if I add `dhcp6: false` I still get a fracking `ipv6` but no `ipv4` 
I kept a `tail -f /var/log/syslog` open for the whole time and nothing useful shows up.

If I run `dhclient -r ens9 && dhclient ens9` the interface does get an `ipv4` and the network starts working (for instance that's how I got it to work during the install process). I can ssh in it fine, even tho sometimes the network hangs (but honestly this is minor if at least I can get the DHCP config working ).

So even tho I do have a horrible workaround that I prefer not to use, I really want to understand why the default "Canonical" (pun intended) way is not working for me, and I'm currently out of options on where to knock my head.

I pretty much set off to reuse an old machine to have some fun, and I ended up being totally frustrated , kind of made me remember why I stopped using Linux as a desktop operating system.

**Update:**

1. Testing with `networkctl`

this is the output after hours of running

> link:ens9 type:ether operational:degraded setup:configuring

just after reboot it looks quite different:

> link:ens9 type:ether operational:off setup:managed

but I suspect it's because of the optional parameter if I remove the `optional`

`netplan generate && netplan apply` I got back to the initial state of:

> link:ens9 type:ether operational:degraded setup:configuring

rebooting without optional, after stalling at host and network name lookups gives me:

> link:ens9 type:ether operational:degraded setup:configuring

if I run `dhclient -r ens9 && dhclient ens9` it goes from `degraded` to `routable`

2. I remembred this laptop also comes with an integrated ethernet port (it's so long since I've seen one that I didn't even remember they existed ), so I pulled the Thunderbolt Dongle, connected my cable directly to the build-in port, updated the config file with the new interface name, and when to the usual paces of generate, apply, even rebooting.
   Result: Nothing changes, same exact behavior in any way.
   From this, I would say it's def not an HW problem but a SW problem. The biggest one being: there are zero logs (as far as I can tell) explaining why `netplan` is not doing whatever it needs to do with the DHCP client. Even using the `-d` switch, or trying (`netplan try`) gives zero information.
3. So I thought perhaps putting a server build on a laptop could be not the best idea, so I downloaded and tried Ubuntu Desktop 21.10. Same behavior.
4. After a further investigation I found on the internet it might be a problem with firmware and/or kernel modules. I then proceeded with:
   `apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer` and `modprobe b43` but nothing changed, same exact behavior and the DHCP refusing to do its job if not manually stimulated :(

background: Linux has been my primary (and only) OS from 1994 to 2004 when I switched to OSX. I keep using it on servers but with the modern "lazy cloud platforms and docker" I haven't had to deal with network config issues for a long long time and, in full disclosure, I just found out today about `netplan`. While my personal opinion is that is a poor choice for a language to use white spaces as a means to define blocks, I am very familiar with `yaml` and paranoid in checking/counting those pesky whitespaces.

Comment: In stock config is `ethernets` instead of `ethernet`

Comment: if I change it to `ethernet` when I run `netplan generate` it complains that the singular is invalid. So I guess the stock config is right? 

Comment: oh sorry, only now I see what you meant.
Because of the lack of network, I copied the config instead of copy/pasting it, and being dyslexic doesn't help to see my typing errors. I'll fix the post. Thanks.

Comment: The configuration (with `ethernets`!) looks correct.  If dhclient works, networkd should also work.  Can you show the output of `networkctl` on this system?

Comment: link:ens9  type:ether operational:degraded setup:configuring
this is the output after hours of running

just after reboot it looks quite different:
link:ens9  type:ether operational:off setup:managed
but I suspect it's because of the `optional` parameter

if I remove the "optional" and `netplan generate && netplan apply` I got back to the initial state of:
link:ens9  type:ether operational:degraded setup:configuring

rebooting without `optional`, after stalling at `host and network name lookups` gives me:
link:ens9  type:ether operational:degraded setup:configuring

Comment: meh, sorry, posting removes my formatting. Long story short it's: degraded and configuring

Comment: if I run `dhclient -r ens9 && dhclient ens9` it goes from `degraded` to `routable`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Admittedly out of frustration at the end I ended up making it work in the dirty way possible (the one I wanted to avoid):

Just running it through `rc.local`

This "works" as the interface is quite unstable, it almost looks like there's "something underneath" doing "something".

Setting a static IP solves the instability but well, it's not the point...

Answer (score 0):

It's not much but at least I found out why those `ipv6` addresses were showing up:
apparently `netplan` takes the liberty to add extra steps to the network config during the `generate` command (not very cool if you ask me).
The fix is:

1. add `link-local: []` to netplan's interface configuration and generate
2. check your `/run/systemd/network/` dir for the generated files

Idk, the more I dig the more I find this `netplan` pesky, confusing, not helpful, and worst of all completely against the *unix philosophy. It's just hiding stuff and making it more complicated, trying to fix something that wasn't broken...