# Network Cable Unplugged After waking from suspension after Upgrading to 21.04

Tags: networking, suspend

I've just upgraded to 21.04. Now after waking from suspension. The network cable is shown as unplugged. I found a solution. which is I have to remove and reinstall the ethernet device driver. Via modprobe -r and then -i. Everytime after waking from suspend.

Is there any elegant and simple solution to fix this?

Upgraded from 20.10 to 21.04

```
lspci -nn | grep -i ethernet

04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1969:e091] (rev 13)


sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 13
       serial: 44:8a:5b:46:f3:a5
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx driverversion=5.11.0-18-generic duplex=full ip=192.168.1.158 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:f7900000-f793ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3160
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: wlp5s0
       version: 83
       serial: 30:3a:64:5f:7b:1b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.11.0-18-generic firmware=17.3216344376.0 3160-17.ucode latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:35 memory:f7800000-f7801fff



inxi -Fxz
System:    Kernel: 5.11.0-18-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.1 Desktop: GNOME 3.38.4 
           Distro: Ubuntu 21.04 (Hirsute Hippo) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Micro-Star product: GP70 2PE v: REV:1.0 serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: Micro-Star model: MS-175A v: REV:1.0 serial: <filter> BIOS: American Megatrends v: E175AIMS.109 
           date: 05/27/2014 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT1 charge: 6.8 Wh condition: 6.8/48.8 Wh (14%) model: MSI Corp. MS-175A status: Full 
CPU:       Info: Quad Core model: Intel Core i7-4710HQ bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Haswell rev: 3 L2 cache: 6 MiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 39909 
           Speed: 2561 MHz min/max: 1800/3500 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 2561 2: 2852 3: 2695 4: 2582 5: 2495 6: 2494 7: 2467 
           8: 2487 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: i915 v: kernel 
           bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce 840M] vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: nvidia v: 460.80 bus ID: 01:00.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa 
           resolution: 1600x900 
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce 840M/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 460.80 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: snd_hda_intel 
           v: kernel bus ID: 00:03.0 
           Device-2: Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Definition Audio vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
           bus ID: 00:1b.0 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.11.0-18-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: alx v: kernel port: d000 
           bus ID: 04:00.0 
           IF: enp4s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Intel Wireless 3160 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: d000 bus ID: 05:00.0 
           IF: wlp5s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
Bluetooth: Device-1: Intel Bluetooth wireless interface type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus ID: 1-1.3:4 
           Report: ID: hci0 state: up running pscan bt-v: 2.1 lmp-v: 4.0 address: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 931.51 GiB used: 596.27 GiB (64.0%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Toshiba model: MQ01ABD100 size: 931.51 GiB temp: 39 C 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 914.9 GiB used: 596.27 GiB (65.2%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda4 
           ID-2: /boot/efi size: 512 MiB used: 4 KiB (0.0%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/sda3 
Swap:      ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 23.8 MiB (1.2%) file: /swapfile 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 84.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 42 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 365 Uptime: 7h 58m Memory: 15.55 GiB used: 5.48 GiB (35.2%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: 
           gcc: 10.3.0 Packages: 2784 Shell: Bash v: 5.1.4 inxi: 3.3.01 

 cat /etc/network/interfaces and cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
cat: /etc/network/interfaces: No such file or directory
cat: and: No such file or directory
cat: cat: No such file or directory
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Update.   I followed the suggestions here. The drivers are not automatically removed and installed after waking from suspension.
https://askubuntu.com/a/1058760/1247412

Comment: Maybe it's your kernel. Can you run `inxi -Fxz` in a terminal and edit the output into your question? You might have to install inxi with `sudo apt install inxi`. You can also try `nmcli network off && nmcli network on` as a temporary solution.

Comment: What version Ubuntu did you upgrade from? [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1346226/edit) and show me `lspci -nn | grep -i ethernet` and `sudo lshw -C network`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: You didn't show me the other details that I requested...

Comment: @heynnema

I can't seem to paste long paragraphs.

Comment: Don't paste that output into comments... rather... as edit to your original question... paste them there, select the pasted text, then click the {} icon.

Comment: @heynnema I have added to my OP

Comment: Thanks. Different ethernet card than I was expecting. Show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Comment: @raffles  I have added to the OP. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using cat 5e or cat 6 cables?

Comment: @heynnema Added to the OP. Thanks.  I'm using Cat 6.

Comment: I suspect a problem with the alx driver. Boot to the GRUB menu and select the prior 20.10 kernel and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: @heynnema I did what you mentioned. Choose the previous linux kernel at the grub menu. kernel 5.8. And yes the ethernet is connected after waking from suspension.

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1931301

Comment: @heynnema pls see the new section I added at the bottom.

Comment: @johnlau You didn't exactly follow the examples shown at that link. Try again. It might work as a workaround.

Comment: @heynnema  Its working now. Thanks.

Comment: @johnlau I added Update #2 to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... in `terminal` do `nm-connection-editor` and select your Wired Connection to edit.

- confirm Device ethernet address
- confirm WOL
- change Link Negotiation to Automatic

  - or try Manual/1000Mb/full
- reboot and retest

[image]

Also verify Connect automatically...

[image]

**Update #1:**

See bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1931301

**Update #2:**

Used workaround fixes from [Ubuntu 18.04 - Ethernet disconnected after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029250/ubuntu-18-04-ethernet-disconnected-after-suspend/1058760)

Comment: Check your spelling in the first line, second shaded block :)

Comment: @Raffles Thanks! The coffee hasn't fully kicked in yet :-)

Comment: These are the defaults in nm-connection-editor 

Connect Automatically with priority -999
Link Negotiation - Manual 100mb/s ( although it is 1000mbs normally ) 
WOL - Default

I tried Automatic Link Negotiation. and also manually 1gps. Still doesn't work.

Comment: @johnlau Change Connect Automatically priority=0, and Link Neg=ignored. See if there's any difference.

Comment: @johnlau Show me `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` and `grep -i GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX /etc/default/grub`.

Comment: @johnlau When it fails, instead of reloading the alx module, try `sudo dhclient enp4s0` and see if that brings it back.

Comment: @heynnema  i set priroty to 0 and link Neg to ignored. No differences.

Comment: @heynnema cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume


cat: /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume: No such file or directory

Comment: @heynnema     grep -i GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

Comment: @heynnema    sudo dhclient enp4s0
RTNETLINK answers: No such device

Comment: @johnlau Add yourself to the bug report that I gave a link for in a prior comment. Add a "this effects me too" statement.

Comment: @heynnema Done.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with upgrade from 20.08 to 21.04, used wireless for a bit and today reinstalled 21.04 from scratch assuming it was some upgrading bug.

Fresh Install still fails the same way.

mike@mike-XPS-8930:~$ lspci -nn | grep -i ethernet
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1969:e0a1] (rev 10)
mike@mike-XPS-8930:~$

Answer (score 0):

I think a reboot is too heavy and uneeded. Simply reload network card kernel modules can rejuvenate that dead network card.

In recent time i have same problems with my network card to go up from sleep to ram. But in the past i am 100% sure i has no problems. I suspect is the new kernel drivers, 5.11.0-25-generic,  to blame here

So in Ubuntu 20.04 with `lshw -C network` i get the driver name, then with `modprobe -rv driver_name` will remove and with `modprobe -v driver_name` my cable ethernet network is back

Nothing else work, `systemctl restart NetworkManager` cant wake up my ethernet card without modprobe driver recicle step. I suspect is that WOL thing the culprit i mean they are waiting for a lan wake up not a local resume from sleep

```
aug 27 01:54:53 berbecel NetworkManager[2357602]: <info>  [1630018493.3313] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
aug 27 01:54:53 berbecel NetworkManager[2357602]: <info>  [1630018493.3314] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
aug 27 01:54:53 berbecel NetworkManager[2357602]: <info>  [1630018493.3317] device (enp2s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
aug 27 01:54:53 berbecel NetworkManager[2357602]: <info>  [1630018493.3692] device (enp2s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
aug 27 01:54:53 berbecel NetworkManager[2357602]: <info>  [1630018493.3881] dhcp4 (enp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction
aug 27 01:54:53 berbecel NetworkManager[2357602]: <info>  [1630018493.3881] dhcp4 (enp2s0): state changed bound -> done
aug 27 01:54:53 berbecel NetworkManager[2357602]: <info>  [1630018493.3920] device (enp2s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
aug 28 02:24:11 berbecel NetworkManager[2357602]: <info>  [1630106651.3796] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
aug 28 02:24:11 berbecel NetworkManager[2357602]: <info>  [1630106651.3797] device (enp2s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
aug 28 02:24:11 berbecel NetworkManager[2357602]: <info>  [1630106651.3812] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
```

but then

```
aug 28 02:47:59 berbecel NetworkManager[2368981]: <info>  [1630108079.2431] device (enp2s0): driver '(null)' does not support carrier detection.
aug 28 02:47:59 berbecel NetworkManager[2368981]: <info>  [1630108079.2433] device (enp2s0): driver 'alx' does not support carrier detection.
aug 28 02:47:59 berbecel NetworkManager[2368981]: <info>  [1630108079.2436] manager: (enp2s0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
aug 28 02:47:59 berbecel NetworkManager[2368981]: <info>  [1630108079.2445] device (enp2s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
aug 28 02:47:59 berbecel NetworkManager[2368981]: <info>  [1630108079.2565] device (enp2s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
aug 28 02:47:59 berbecel NetworkManager[2368981]: <info>  [1630108079.2577] device (enp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'rdslink' (7ef38c4e-886b-3738-b740-eb3b676cde2d)
aug 28 02:47:59 berbecel NetworkManager[2368981]: <info>  [1630108079.2578] device (enp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
aug 28 02:47:59 berbecel NetworkManager[2368981]: <info>  [1630108079.2586] device (enp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
aug 28 02:47:59 berbecel NetworkManager[2368981]: <info>  [1630108079.2592] device (enp2s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'config-failed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
aug 28 02:47:59 berbecel NetworkManager[2368981]: <warn>  [1630108079.2606] device (enp2s0): Activation: failed for connection 'rdslink'
```

so look like `device (enp2s0): driver 'alx' does not support carrier detection.` means my QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet has no WOL suport and going to sleep means will sleep forewer waiting for a WOl signal who will never arrive?

Comment: Well for Ubuntu Linux 20.04, my distro, is enough to recycle the alx network card drivers. If NetworkManager service is already running the nic card will be autodetected imediately, if not will be needed a NetworkManager service restart. This means:

`sudo modprobe -rv alx
sudo modprobe -v alx`

is enough. If not a

`sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` should be enough