# Wired connection works for a while after fresh install then stops

Tags: networking, 20.04, ethernet, connection

Have an unused laptop that I want to run Ubuntu on (and leave in a corner to run various scripts). I installed Ubuntu Desktop and a wired connection worked for a while then just stopped working (wifi works). I re-did a fresh install and it works for a while then stops working. There is nothing wrong with the cable or connection; I tried two different ethernet cables on two different laptops as well, there is no issue with the router, cable or internet connectivity.

I have tried everything I have come across on Google and these forums but nothing has worked. It just says "Cable Unplugged". It has on one occasion reconnected but goes away again.

Anyone encountered this before and have a solution? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is some output.

```
sudo lshw -c network


*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 01
       serial: 40:f0:2f:74:52:ec
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=5.8.0-55-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.77 latency=0 link=yes multicas
       resources: irq:18 memory:f7900000-f797ffff memory:f7980000-f798ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 10
       serial: 0c:54:a5:1d:f4:6e
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiati
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx driverversion=5.8.0-55-generic latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=tw
       resources: irq:19 memory:f7800000-f783ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
```

Comment: See bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1931301

Comment: See another similar post https://askubuntu.com/questions/1346226/network-cable-unplugged-after-waking-from-suspension-after-upgrading-to-21-04

Comment: So nothing was working, none of the proposed solutions. I started thinking it must be hardware issue then. I got a USB to Ethernet adapter and the connection works flawlessly. Looks like a loose connection somewhere in the wires.

It was a pure coincidence that the Ethernet was connecting after a fresh install, probably because I would wiggle it slightly and it would connect.

Appreciate the responses! I'll use the adapter as the speeds are sufficient. Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as reported by the OP, it was a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a loose connection in the hardware as a USB to Ethernet adapter is working flawlessly so far, not a software issue. Grrr, spent a lot of time on this but such is life. Appreciate the help everyone