# LAN issue while using tlp

Tags: lan, tlp

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I am facing a LAN connection problem which I posted on this community 3 times before but didn't get answers. 
The problem is when I start my laptop it will connect to the LAN but once I disconnect it it won't reconnect. Then I will have to put the laptop in sleep mode and then it would reconnect. Every time I reinstalled Ubuntu and the problem didn't showed up for the first 3-4 days and then again the same problem happens.

But this time I think I have figured out the reason behind this. there was no issue till today when I installed tlp and started it. Only after tlp it showed the same problem again. I googled and got to know that tlp activation changes some settings in order to save battery. 
Is it possible that tlp is the culprit. If so is there any way I can disable a particular setting so that tlp keeps working and I get rid of the problem.

And yes I have my laptop dual booted with windows 10 and there is no such issue in windows 10. So certainly it is specific to Ubuntu.

Output of

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:832b]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723de
```

After this I suspended and ran lspci and I got this

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Skylake Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d4e (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430] (rev 83)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723
```

Please note that I am not having tlp installed right now. Because of this problem I removed it.

Comment: Do you know which Network card you have and kernel driver name being used?

Comment: It's realtek. And I am using kernel 4.15. pardon if that's not what you are asking. Can you give me any commands which can answer your questions on the terminal

Comment: Sure. Type `lsmod | grep rtl` in the terminal. Then paste the results into your question.

Comment: btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             548864  33 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb

Comment: that 2 lines got mixed up

Comment: btrtl                  16384  1 btusb

Comment: bluetooth             548864  33 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb

Comment: above 2 lines appear in the output

Comment: I was expecting something like `rtl8169`. I'll check my notes after work.

Comment: After a new boot, paste this into your terminal: `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`. Copy the output to clipboard (Highlight with mouse, right click, select copy). Edit your question above and paste the clipboard into your question (`Ctrl`+`V`). Save your question edit. Suspend machine, resume and repeat the `lspci` command into the terminal. Did the kernel driver in use disappear? Thanks.

Comment: I have edited the question with outputs

Comment: This answer hopefully solves the problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/950871/need-to-reconnect-ethernet-cable-to-get-it-work-after-docking-laptop-into-dock-s/962090#962090

Comment: I think the problem is due to tlp. So may be I need to change the tlp configuration file. Otherwise it is working great

Comment: I was probably using TLP when I wrote the answer.

Comment: don't you think changing the tlp file configuration might work

Comment: I've posted an answer with modifications to TLP you can try out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLP will power off devices during suspend to save battery life. This answer: [Need to reconnect ethernet cable to get it work after docking laptop into dock station](https://askubuntu.com/questions/950871/need-to-reconnect-ethernet-cable-to-get-it-work-after-docking-laptop-into-dock-s/962090#962090). will reload the R8169 drivers for you realtek network card and might be a sufficient approach.

Another approach is to leave power to the network card during suspend. To do this use `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/tlp` and insert these lines:

```
USB_BLACKLIST="10ec:8168"
USB_BLACKLIST="103c:832b"
```

Save the file and reboot.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85034/discussion-on-answer-by-wineunuuchs2unix-lan-issue-while-using-tlp).